# TYPO3 RTE Bold button wrap

Tags: typo3, rte, typo3-7.6.x

At some point (maybe in a recent update) the wrap that the bold button applies changed from:

```
<b>Text</b>
```

to:

```
<span style="font-weight:bold;">Text</span>
```

Is there a way to specify what the wrap is?
My problem is that I need to change the font-family when it is bold and not the weight, so I would rather have it use the b tags...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TS Config I had mistakenly put:

```
RTE.default.useCSS = 1
```

By setting this to 0 or removing it entirely, the RTE will use `<b>` tags for bold instead of inline style.